# How to create a Javascript/Typescript Map dynamically without for loop?

Tags: javascript, typescript, dictionary, functional-programming

I want to dynamically create a Typescript `Map<string, Person>` object where `Person` is a class.

I can use `for` loop to create a map like this:

```
function getInitializedPersonMap(size){
  const personMap = new Map<string, Person>();
  for (let index = 0; index < size; index++) {
    personMap.set(index.toString(), {} as Person);
  }
  return personMap;
}
```

However, I am trying to build a habit of moving away from 'for' loops and use functions like map, filter, reduce.

My attempt without loop looks like this which is not quite as readable as one with `for` loop:

```
function getInitializedPersonMap(size){
   return new Map<string, Person>(
      Array.from(new Array(size), (_, index) => [
        index.toString(),
        {} as Person,
      ])
    );
}
```

For scenarios like this is this an overkill to avoid 'for' loops?

Comment: I have edited my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**Map**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), notice the type has been explicitly mentioned.

```
var result = sizeArr.map((i): [string, Person] => [i, {} as Person]);
```

As @VLAZ mentioned that size is an number, so use [**Array.from**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) to flatten the array from target size.

```
let sizeArr = Array.from(Array(n).keys());
```

Comment: `size` seems to be a number, not an array.

Comment: In the first example OP provided a working code, which is based on loop. Seems from there size is an array. OP needs to clarify more.

Comment: @NavoneelTalukdar Just to understand what you are suggesting is to use map over Array.from() overload that takes a mapping function to make it more readable. Yes this is much better. But I was trying to arrive at a way which doesnt include creating additional Array to loop over. Now to get the desired map I will still have to pass the result to a Map constructor. var result = sizeArr.map((i): [string, Person] => [i, {} as Person]);  const resultToBeReturned = new Map<string, Person>(result);

Answer (score 0):

If from the very beginning you know the values, then is pretty straightforward:

```
  const personMap = new Map<string, Person>([
    ['value1', new Person()],
    ['value2', new Person()],
    ['value3', new Person()]
  ]);
```

If what you want is to create the Map based on some existing generated Array, then you can:

```
const arrayLength = 5;
const inputArray = Array.from({ length: arrayLength }, (_, index) => [index + '', new Person()]);

const theMap = new Map<string, Person>(
  inputArray.map(x => [x[0], x[1]] as [string, Person])
);
```

Comment: OP's code shows that the size can be anything and should be dynamic.

Comment: Thanks @JoseGuzman, looks like with your solution, we end up using both Array.from overload that takes a mapping function along with another call to map in the Map constructor.